# LateX Tikz: How can I rotate a line

Tags: tikz, xelatex

I tried to rotate a line, several lines, with scope, but I don't know how.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (4,0);
\coordinate (C) at (6,2);
\coordinate (D) at (2,2);
\begin{scope}[rotate=30]
    \draw (A) -- (B) --(C) -- (D) --cycle;
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[rotate=60]
\draw (2,0) ellipse (3 cm and 1.5cm);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I'm expecting a rotated parallelogram by 30°.
I tried a rotation of an ellipse. This works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using absolute coordinates. If you replace them by relative coordinates, you'll get rotated shapes:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (4,0);
\coordinate (C) at (6,2);
\coordinate (D) at (2,2);
\begin{scope}[rotate=30]
    \draw (A) -- ++(0,1) -- ++(1,0) -- ++(0,-1) --cycle;
    \draw (D) rectangle ++(3,3);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[rotate=60]
\draw (2,0) ellipse (3 cm and 1.5cm);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Now if you wanted to keep your absolute coordinates, you could transform the canvas:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[]
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (4,0);
\coordinate (C) at (6,2);
\coordinate (D) at (2,2);
\begin{scope}[transform canvas={rotate=30}]
    \draw (A) -- (B) --(C) -- (D) --cycle;
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[rotate=60]
\draw (2,0) ellipse (3 cm and 1.5cm);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```